# How to hide button in Dynamics 365 app for Outlook?

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics365-app-outlook

How can I hide the “Add as Lead” in Dynamics 365 app for Outlook?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `Lead` entity from the Assets/artifacts of App for Outlook (AFO UCI model driven app), then this will not list the `Add as Lead` option. It will also remove other functionalities related to Lead entity in app. This is the only way, if you wanted to use Lead in other areas of AFO - then this is impossible to hide.

[image]

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/posts/dynamics-365-app-for-outlook-part-9---app-for-outlook-components)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Contact, Lead, and Account tables, but I still have the three options "Add as Contact", as so on.

I noticed there is another table called Connection which seems to contain only relationships. Contact, Lead, and Account are in the Connection table as relationships, and the three custom tables that I added to App for Outlook don't appear.